Function and private storage account networking
I have made my storage account private and only allow access from selected virtual networks or IP addresses.
Since then I cant run my function and it fails with the error 500 internal server error which is not very imformative.  Tried to look into Diagnostic Console for more infromative error and I found this:
[Error] System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Not really helpfull.
Im sure its related to netowkring issue.
So I would like to configure Vnet on my function app. Things I tried:

I tried  Outbound traffic configuration



Then I tried to choose the virtual network and subnebt where My Private Endpoints of Storage account reside but I have this issue.



To fix the above issues I tried to make the delegation


But I get the error saying: Failed to save subnet ERROR: Delegations of subnet "mysubnet name" cannot be chnaged from [] to  [Microsoft.Web/serverFarms] because it is being used by the resource  pe-kv-nll-dev-we-01.nic.888888889-80c0.......
Then I also tried to add the service endpoint that you see above Microsfot.Web but did not work either.
Any ideas how can I do so? Im new to function apps, maybe I should add the IP address of Storage account to my function app under the Outbound addresses? if so how can I do so?

You need a different subnet in the VNET for the outbound VNET integration in the Function App. Then if private DNS works correctly, your requests for Storage will get routed through the private endpoint.

Would you be able to post as an answer with little bit more details?

To resolve your networking issue in the Azure Function App, create the Virtual network with minimum two subnets where One is for inbound and the other is for outbound configuration:

Open your Storage Account > Networking >


Select the Option Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses with subnet 1, add your device internet IP, function app inbound IP, checkmark the exceptions section.




In the Function App, Select Networking > Select Outbound VNet Integration to Subnet2, Checkmark the Outbound internet traffic, Content Storage fields in the configuration as shown in the above screenshot.
After you do, you’ll get the delegation registered in the subnet2 like below screenshot:



In the Function App > Networking > Inbound traffic configuration > Configure the Public Network Access field like below:



Configure the Service Endpoints of Subnet1:


In Simple terms,

Make the one subnet for outbound connectivity and another subnet for inbound traffic to function app, storage account, etc in the Virtual Network.
Subnet1 should has the service endpoints whatever the services are using it and Subnet2 should act as a dedicated outbound to the server farms.
Configure the WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL app setting to 1 in the environment variables for the function app.

Result:


So in my situation then I need to add one more subnet for outbound  traffic.  and how about the the DNS zone configuration? And in which subnet do you have private endpoints (dfs & blob) of  Storage account?

@play_something_good Allow private endpoints in subnet1 and yes to outbound traffic connection needs dedicated subnet.

I have done exact set up as you have provided but still having same issue 500 internal server error.  I made storage account private and it started a process but failed when trying to access the KV from specific ip address that was listed below outbound addresses from Function app. I whitelisited that specific IP on KV and worked. Then I whitelisted same IP on Storage but did not work. Error is not really helpfull. where can I get better detailed error to see where does it go wrong?

okay, I managed to make it work.  In addtiong to above things that you have listed 1) I had to also whitelist the second subnet on Storage account 2) also, customer is using the managed identity for function app and I had to give  the storage blob data contributor role to that managed identity

I'm glad it worked.
